# Does DisplayActionSheet exist in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: xamarin.android, dialogfragment

I am new to mobile development. I'm trying to write an app in both Xamarin iOS and Xamarin Android. After searching for a couple of days, I keep finding that DisplayActionSheet is part of Xamarin Forms, but I can't find the equivalent in Xamarin Android. Does DisplayActionSheet not exist? Is there anything else I can use to get the same look and effect?

Thank you!

Update: Here's my progress... 
I'm trying to make a dialog that looks like this the image here: https://www.google.com/search?q=displayactionsheet+image&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS752US754&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=EWVc1vOm1JJrhM%253A%252CYaPWhxv5zFphhM%252C_&usg=__v_-JK4lHAj8k50h5iknuPLPc8PM%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbz66zzZHaAhUKY6wKHXyxB64Q9QEIKTAA#imgrc=EWVc1vOm1JJrhM:
So far, I can get the image to slide up and the buttons to respond correctly, but the one thing I'm missing is the behavior when the user clicks outside of the dialog. I want it to be dismissed, but nothing is happening. Thank you for your help!

Here is my code:

```
//MyActivity.cs

public class MyActivity : Activity
{
    FrameLayout _fragmentContainer;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MyView);
        var listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.myView);
        listView.Adapter = new EmailSettingsAdapter(this);
        TextView action = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.actionText);

        _fragmentContainer = FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.frameContainer);

        action.Click += click;
    }

    private void click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FragmentTransaction transaction =     FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        MonthlyStmtFragment fragment = new MonthlyStmtFragment();
        transaction.Add(_fragmentContainer.Id, fragment, "Fragment");
        transaction.Commit();
        _fragmentContainer.TranslationY = 1800;
        _fragmentContainer.Animate().TranslationYBy(-600).SetDuration(500);
    }
}

//MyFragment.cs
public class MyFragment : DialogFragment
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.FragmentLayout, container, false);

        TextView text1 = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text1);
        text1.Click += delegate {
            Dismiss();
            Toast.MakeText(Activity, "selected", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        };

        TextView cancel = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.cancelText);
        cancel.Click += delegate {
            Dismiss();
            Toast.MakeText(Activity, "cancel", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        };

        return view;
    }

//FragmentLayout.axml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">
<TextView
    android:text="Title Here"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/titleView1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#fff5f5f5"
    android:textSize="8dp"
    android:textColor="#ff9e9e9e"
    android:padding="10dp" />
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:background="#ffbdbdbd" />
<TextView
    android:text="Text 1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:background="#fff5f5f5"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#ff1e88e5"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cancelText"
    android:background="#fff5f5f5"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:textColor="#ff1e88e5"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/pop-ups-images/alert.png&imgrefurl=https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/pop-ups&h=384&w=640&tbnid=S6HmOW6AsPhy4M:&tbnh=160&tbnw=266&usg=__OACA0JEKuAdtulsWUe0TQie4CGI%3D&vet=10ahUKEwiFnpLuhYraAhWLKY8KHaoNB3gQ9QEILDAA..i&docid=6yZO8MeVLCZPZM&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFnpLuhYraAhWLKY8KHaoNB3gQ9QEILDAA

Comment: More like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/pop-ups. First picture under "Guiding Users Through Tasks"

Comment: I have answered have a look, if that's what you are looking for then kindly mark as correct answer so others can find it too

Comment: I have updated my ans also i want to know if you want to display the dialog in the same way .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is AlertDialog Class in android :

> A subclass of Dialog that can display one, two or three buttons.

Following are the detailed guide you can work with to achieve it :

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-show-alert-dialog-in-android-using-xamarin

http://stacktips.com/tutorials/xamarin/alertdialog-and-dialogfragment-example-in-xamarin-android

For Customization of this you can use the following :

http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2015/11/custom-alertdialog-example-in.html

Goodluck, Happy Coding!

```
 class DialogFragmentExitPopUp : DialogFragment
{
    public static Activity mActivity;
    public DialogFragmentExitPopUp NewInstance(Activity activity,Bundle bundle)
    {
        var fragment = new DialogFragmentExitPopUp();
        fragment.Arguments = bundle;
        DialogFragmentExitPopUp.mActivity = activity;
        return fragment;
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle SavedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ExitPopUp, container, false);
        Button ButtonYes = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ExitYes);
        Button ButtonNo = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ExitNo);
        ButtonYes.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor("#2466A3"));
        ButtonNo.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor("#2466A3"));
        ButtonYes.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);
        ButtonNo.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);
        Dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        Dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        return view;
    }

}
```

You are not calling the constructor which is causing the issue initializing it like how I have shown you will do it.

And this is the code for calling the actual dialog:

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        Fragment fragmentPrev = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("dialog");
        if (fragmentPrev != null)
            fragmentTransaction.Remove(fragmentPrev);

        fragmentTransaction.AddToBackStack(null);
        //create and show the dialog
        DialogFragmentExitPopUp dialogFragment = new DialogFragmentExitPopUp().NewInstance(this, null);
        dialogFragment.Show(fragmentTransaction, "dialog");
```

Comment: Thank you @G.hakim. I'm trying to get the dialog to come up from the bottom of the screen, I hope I can use your suggestions to make it work. I will look it over in the morning.

Comment: Surely, if you need any help you can ask here

Comment: I was able to get the look I want using a FrameLayout as a fragment container (in my Activity). Then created a DialogFragment, that gets added to the container. I use an animation to slide the fragment container from the bottom up.My only problem now is that I can't figure out how to do `Dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)`, when I have this line in my fragment.cs code, I get an exception saying Dialog is null.

Comment: Any other ideas? @G.hakim

Comment: Well if you have teamviewer i can help you out! @Monica if not you can update your code here and i can give it a check

Comment: I will start a different question.

Comment: It would be better if you just update your implementation here starting a new thread makes no sense

Comment: comments don't allow for formatting of code, at least I can't get it to work, it gets all mixed together.

Comment: No update your question there must be an option up there if you look closely called edit check for it

Comment: I looked at your code, but that makes the fragment pop up (I've tried it), not **slide up** like I'm intending to do. To make it slide up, I need to use the container which then makes me not use the `dialogFragment.Show`. Is there a different way to animate the dialog? I've been researching for a week, haven't found anything that works yet. @G.hakim

Comment: Thank you @G.hakim, your link pointed me in the right direction even though it was android and not Xamarin.Android. I used `DialogFragment.Show` and then added a window animation by overriding `OnActivityCreated`. It finally works the way I wanted it.

Comment: Well then I'm happy that it works like you wanted it to work goodluck for the future.@Monica Also you should edit my ans and put the stuff that you did for other users who are looking for something similar